# Sharing RNN State Distributed TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to implement a synchronous distributed Recurrent Neural Network using TensorFlow on multiple servers. Here's the link to my code:
https://github.com/tushar00jain/spark-ml/blob/master/rnn-sync.ipynb

I'm not sure how to make the `_current_state` variable be shared across all the servers, which you can find in the "training loop" section of my code. I have also provided the code below. I want the computations within the same batch to happen in parallel but I think it's still computing separate RNNs on each worker server and updating the parameters on the parameter server separately. I know this because I am printing the `_current_state` variable after I run the graph for each batch. Also, the `_total_loss` for the same global step is different on each worker server.

I'm following the instructions provided at the following links: https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed#replicated_training
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SyncReplicasOptimizer

```
        sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target)
        queue_runners = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS)
        sv.start_queue_runners(sess, queue_runners)

        tf.logging.info('Started %d queues for processing input data.',
                        len(queue_runners))

        if is_chief:
                sv.start_queue_runners(sess, chief_queue_runners)
                sess.run(init_tokens_op)

        print("{0} session ready".format(datetime.now().isoformat()))
        #####################################################################

        ########################### training loop ###########################
        _current_state = np.zeros((batch_size, state_size))
        for batch_idx in range(args.steps):
            if sv.should_stop() or tf_feed.should_stop():
                break

            batchX, batchY = feed_dict(tf_feed.next_batch(batch_size))

            print('==========================================================')
            print(_current_state)

            if args.mode == "train":
                _total_loss, _train_step, _current_state, _predictions_series, _global_step = sess.run(
                [total_loss, train_step, current_state, predictions_series, global_step],
                feed_dict={
                    batchX_placeholder:batchX,
                    batchY_placeholder:batchY,
                    init_state:_current_state
                })

                print(_global_step, batch_idx)
                print(_current_state)
                print('==========================================================')

                if _global_step % 5 == 0:
                    print("Step", _global_step, "Loss", _total_loss)
```

How can I share the `_current_state` and update it so that all the servers have the same state for the same `global_step`?

Comment: What is the purpose of _current_state? Do you want synchronous training? I've implemented distributed rnn, but without a current state :-/

Comment: how can I do that without having to feed init_state to feed_dict?

Comment: by using a global_step - but I was wondering what the purpose of current_step is. Here is a model of mine: https://github.com/derdav3/tf-sparql/blob/master/graph_vec_nn/rnn-distributed.py

Comment: hmm i'm doing it a bit differently. Here's my code: https://github.com/tushar00jain/spark-ml/blob/master/rnn.ipynb

I'm just setting the initial state in static_rnn and updating it to pass to sess.run in the training loop. I wonder if this is still valid for parallel computation

Comment: I printed out the `_current_state` variable and it seems that separate RNNs are being trained on each server, which probably update the parameter server. Do you know if this is intended? If not, would you know how I can share the variable to be updated in each iteration?

Comment: in asynchronous training: yes, in synchronous training: no. Depends on what you want....

Comment: thanks! I guess I was hoping for a synchronous training in that case, which can parallelise computations within one batch.

Comment: both have pro and contra.. (also if you find good synchronous examples let me know ;) ).. in the (limited) time I explored distributed tf I found that nodes/machines unexpectedly lagged or are slow. so if you train asynchronously you get the most epochs out of your session - with synchonous training you would wait

Comment: will do that :)

Comment: Would you happen to know how I share the state of the RNN globally?
I added the code as per the documentation for synchronous training. The reason why I want to manually update the state is that if you don't specify (like in your example), it would reset to a zero tensor at the beginning of every batch.

Comment: isn't that handled by the syncreplicaoptimizer? I dont know how to do it manually.

Comment: far as I know it guarantees that the weights will be updated after the specified number of gradients have been collected but the state used for calculating losses is still different on all machines ... time to look at the source code